# How to compute cosine similarity when the vectors are represented using non-orthogonal bases?

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm trying to use a vector space model by not assuming the terms to be pairwise orthogonal. But I'm finding it hard to figure out how to compute the similarity when the bases are not orthogonal

Comment: Yes, in the non-orthogonal case it's much messier, both theoretically and numerically...

Answer (score 0):

Cosine similarity extends in a straightforward way to arbitrary inner product spaces with a non-Euclidean inner product $\langle,\rangle$:

$$\textrm{similarity}(v,w) = \frac{\langle v, w\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle\langle w,w\rangle}}.$$

In practice you will construct an inner product matrix $M$ with $M_{ij} = \langle b_i, b_j\rangle$ for basis elements $b$, so that $\langle v, w\rangle = v^T M w$.